# eBay API adding Tracking Numbers - Error Number 10007

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

Hi I am using this code to add tracking numbers in eBay SandBox its shows me Success but i am not able to see tracking numbers in my eBay

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CompleteSaleRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>my_ebay_eBayAuthToken</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
    <ItemID>110154684599</ItemID>
  <TransactionID>27387395001</TransactionID>
  <ListingType>Half</ListingType>
  <Shipped>true</Shipped>
  <Shipment>
    <Notes>Item Shipped We are very Glad to have you</Notes>
    <ShipmentTrackingDetails>
      <ShipmentTrackingNumber>1030385557492892794611</ShipmentTrackingNumber>
      <ShippingCarrierUsed>USPSGround</ShippingCarrierUsed>
    </ShipmentTrackingDetails>
  </Shipment>
</CompleteSaleRequest>
```

and it shows me result :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompleteSaleResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2014-12-31T18:32:02.679Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Failure</Ack>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Internal error to the application.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>Internal error to the application.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>10007</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Version>893</Version>
  <Build>E893_CORE_API_17097905_R1</Build>
</CompleteSaleResponse>
```

that means data successfully added. but i am not able to see tracking number in order.

Comment: What makes you so sure about this "means [that the] data [was] successfully added"? Can you please provide some reference? And could you please share which error reference you use for the Ebay API?

Comment: I already display error code :  10007
i read on lots of places its ebay system error. but when i remove 

<ShippingCarrierUsed>USPSGround</ShippingCarrierUsed>

from xml then it shows me 

<ack>success</ack> but still i am not able to see tracking number in ebay. even on testing environment ( on ebay developer we have place where we can see xml result ) shows same thing. now i am not sure where is problem..

Comment: For system errors contact Ebay API support. Tell them which request you did and when it occurs (as you did here). They are able to tell you more and can explain you the situation.

Comment: Thanks for kind replay... i try to find ebay support link but i found one support ticket system for $250 ( 4 hours ) can you please tell me where i can create free ticket to ebay support desk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is eBay end error so contact eBay support

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I noticed another problem is in your XML request itself that may have contributed to the original error code:

```
<ListingType>Half</ListingType>
```

This type tag tells the CompleteSale API you want to work exclusively with half.com, not ebay.com, transactions.   The eBay API sandbox does not support any half.com API paths.  So the above request would be unpredictable in the sandbox.

If you did intend to work with a half.com transaction, well tracking numbers do not show up in My Ebay for those anyway.  They would show up in My Account->Sales->View Shipment Information at half.com web GUI.

Just sayin.